# Create an app that runs in Win7 mode and Metro mode

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro, visual-studio-2013, desktop-application

I want to create an app that runs in desktop mode when installing in Windows 7 and runs in metro mode when installing in Windows 8 (like google chrome).

I have Visual Studio 2013 and I can create apps than run in desktop mode or metro mode, but not both modes

In any case, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately that is not possible by designing one application. You need to create two different application and through the setup, understand which version the operating system has and install the corresponding version. Although you can take advantage of Portable Libraries (See [Cross-Platform Development with the .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) to write most of your codes and then write the UI separately for each environment. The easiest way might be to design your application based on [MVVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) and then almost you need to write your Views twice one for Metro style and one for WPF application although the codes would be quite similar.